# Embedding Other People's Content

Tags: advertising, youtube

I am a little confused about embedding other peoples' content. I understand the idea that people may not appreciate another person using their content without permission for monetary gain. Here is what I don't understand:

1. There are allowed third party players out there which play others' content, this seems to be the same as embedding a video in a webpage/app that doesn't belong to the website owner. Surely they have not gotten permission for every video they display.
2. On the official page regarding Monetizing Youtube (https://developers.google.com/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications), under Video Organization and Discovery it discusses giving users new ways of discovery videos. Is this not embedding other people's content?
3. When they view the video through another webpage/app they still receive compensation for the view. If a person wants to monetize their video, they can choose to monetize it when they upload. Or they can choose to make it public or private.
4. I would think that a monetized video author would appreciate a new avenue for their video to gain another fresh view, but this of course if my own reasoning. I can imagine that some video authors would not like having their video associated with a site or advertisements that they have no control over.
5. On the note above regarding the creation of a new avenue to someone's content, is it possible to monetize the link itself? I.e. get partial credit somehow for being responsible for the view? On YouTube's own sitein the link above, it seems they only way to monetize this would be to through AdSense on another portion of the page. The link above however, suggests that AdSense target areas should be removed from the area where videos are played.

Please clarify what the differences are, and when it may be allowable for people to embed other people's content. To be clear: this is a direct link to the original video, not a re-upload.

Answer (score 2):

> There are allowed third party players out there which play others' content, this seems to be the same as embedding a video in a webpage/app that doesn't belong to the website owner. Surely they have not gotten permission for every video they display.

Indeed. You can use embed features of youtube to put a video in your website. Ads will still be shown and the video's makers will still gain money and view count.

> On the official page regarding Monetizing Youtube (https://developers.google.com/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications), under Video Organization and Discovery it discusses giving users new ways of discovery videos. Is this not embedding other people's content?

That is for Youtube API, and it mostly states that you can't sell the content that isn't yours, also please note that you can't put targeted ads on your page (if it has enough content) or any ads (if it doesn't have enough content) that shows the video:

> However, you cannot run advertisements on pages that play our video content unless there is a significant amount of other important content on the page, meaning that users come to the page to access other content besides the video. In that limited case, you can run ads as long as those ads are targeted to the other content on the page and not to the video or video metadata. For example, if your page displays a video with a news article, blog entry or user profile information, then you can display ads on the page as long as the ads are targeted to the article, blog entry or user profile data.
>
> When they view the video through another webpage/app they still receive compensation for the view. If a person wants to monetize their video, they can choose to monetize it when they upload. Or they can choose to make it public or private.

Yes, they still earn ad money.

> I would think that a monetized video author would appreciate a new avenue for their video to gain another fresh view, but this of course if my own reasoning. I can imagine that some video authors would not like having their video associated with a site or advertisements that they have no control over.

You can put the video on your website, but you can NOT put it on advertisements, as that'd be [Commercial Use without approval](https://developers.google.com/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications). If they don't want their video on your/any website, they can contact you or put a note in the description.

> On the note above regarding the creation of a new avenue to someone's content, is it possible to monetize the link itself? I.e. get partial credit somehow for being responsible for the view? On YouTube's own sitein the link above, it seems they only way to monetize this would be to through AdSense on another portion of the page. The link above however, suggests that AdSense target areas should be removed from the area where videos are played.

You can not monetize the link, but you can put ads on the page if not targeted at video as you said.

> Please clarify what the differences are, and when it may be allowable for people to embed other people's content. To be clear: this is a direct link to the original video, not a re-upload.

You are allowed to embed other people's videos and put advertisements on the page as long as you don't target the ads on the video and have significant amount of content on that page other than that video.

Comment: Nicely done! You have taken several points and addressed them in a very clear and precise way. Cheers!!